# How do I set/force/enable specific (second) monitor to very low resolution in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, resolution

I am using nVidia graphics card. I have two monitors - one normal, 1080p, and second, special display, connected to VGA, capable only of 400x300 pixels. However, since it's very OLD, it's missing any EDID, or similar information, and for some reason Windows thinks it's capable of anything between 1920x1080  and 1024x768. I have added all custom resolutions (8, 16, 24 and 32 bits), but Windows just refuses to even show in resolution selection window anything lower than 1024x768. I've spent considerable time searching forums for how to set display to low resolution, but everything I find is related to VGA mode, or 'low resolution mode', 640x480, enabled in Windows' safe mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you should write up your own `*.INF` file for the monitor, as described in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj133967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at MSDN.

The key idea is that a custom `INF`-file would contain an override for EDID data, including the list of possible resolutions.

If the monitor is *not* hand-made (I believe it is not), you may also search the Internet for the factory-provided `INF`-file. This seems to be very realistic, because the `INF`-files are mostly compatible since the times of Windows NT 3.5.

Comment: I think I stumbled upon true Windows' limitation!

Following your advice, I grabbed Microsoft's own inf for 640x480 monitor, modified it, and forced it upon the unsuspecting monitor. 

However, I am not able to go down to 400x300 - Windows just hangs, I have to manually power cycle the PC. I think it's not really close, because I was able to get 480x360, which is within the monitor's electronics grasp. It displays upper-left part of screen, leaving me with functional display at last. Low and behold: http://i.imgur.com/j9YEU4m.png

Thank you!